# Date format "dd/MM/yyyy" to "yyyy/MM/dd"

Tags: c#

I know this question has been asked before and resolved using various methods.

I am converting a value from a string to a DateTime.

Throughout the project I have used the same CultureInfo, all strings that where converted to date where done using Convert.ToDateTime(), but now there is one text field that refuses to convert.

I have tried:

```
string date = "27/02/2013";
string startdated = (Convert.ToDateTime(date)).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

(converts to datetime and changes it back to sting in my required format. This works fine on everything else)

even

```
Datetime dt = Convert.toDateTime(date); doesn't work 
DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy/MM/dd", format); doesn't work
```

And all give me the same error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.". i receive my date value from a textbox with an ajax calender extender (CalendarExtender.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy" done for display purposes,this also works everywhere else i.e "dd/MM/yyyy" for display and "yyyy/MM/dd" for procedure) except this final value which simply will not change. Everthing is done via my machine with no external servers

Answer (score 4):

Your input string is not in the same format as the format you provde DateTime.ParseExact with.

For this to work

```
DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy/MM/dd", format);
```

You have to enter the date in *year/month/day* format. But your string is in *day/month/year*.

This should work better.

```
string date = "27/02/2013";
DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your date is `date = "27/02/2013";` and your current format *(in `DateTime.ParseExact`)* is `"yyyy/MM/dd"`, **It should be:**

```
"dd/MM/yyyy"
```

So the following code should work.

```
string date = "27/02/2013";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You can also use the format `"d/M/yyyy"` which would take care of single or double digit date/month.

Comment: in my moment of frustration i mis-typed my DateTime.ParseExact(date,"dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); question here. apologies i do have it as "dd/MM/yyyy" and it fails i have since removed my calender extenders and replaced them with a default calender date picker that simply uses the calender as the display and its value passed as the required "yyyy/MM/dd". not exactly what i wanted but it works

Comment: @Domo, happens :), but you may try single digit format `"d/M/yyyy"` in your previous scenario, may be you have single and multiple digits day/month. But glad that your problem is somewhat sorted out.

Comment: thanx for the hint. i did have single and double digits